# Stop executing a page when it is loading

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Actually, when a submit button is clicked, I want to provide a "cancel button" for user to stop loading if the page has taken too long for loading data. I have written some code below, but it is not working when large data is loading.

```
Loading...Please wait a moment...<br/>
<input id="btnModules_Cancel" type="button" value="Cancel" 
  onclick="window.location.href=document.URL;"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

What is going to happen, when the user will click the cancel button? I meam, do you want to redirect a user to a different page?
If you're performing an Ajax request you can try to use [abort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=XMLHttpRequest#abort%28%29) method of `XMLHttpRequest`

Also, if you want server to stop processing your request you can try to utilize [IsClientConnected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.isclientconnected.aspx)

Comment: For example, you are in the "searching product page". When you click the search button, a post back will be triggered. Then you think the searching is taking too long and click the "cancel" button to cancel this action. After the loading is canceled, you can use the searching product filter to narrow down the search result.

Comment: @user1439709, if you're using update panels, or something similar, probably this article can help you step by step. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398789(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: If I am not using the ajaxcontroltoolkit, then I cannot use "Canceling an Asynchronous Postback"...Am I right?

Comment: @user1439709, no, UpdatePanel is not a part of Ajaxcontroltoolkit.

Comment: Thanks! I think the update panel will be my last solution for this case because I don't like using update panel, it sometimes will produce some unexpected issues. By the way, do you have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours, I found this works great for me.

Changed `onclick="window.location.href=document.URL;"`
To      `onclick="StopLoading();"`

```
function StopLoading() {
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
        document.execCommand('Stop');
    } else {
        window.stop();
    }
    alert('Operation Aborted.');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="window.stop();" />
```

Stops the loading..
you can create a function within your script if you want to STOP then REDIRECT to some other page.

http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/client-object-property-method/window-stop.php

```
function stopLoad(){
    window.stop(); //stop loading the page
    window.location = "url.asp"; //takes you somewhere
}
```

execute the function by..

```
    <input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stopLoad()" />
```